# How to preview the result of markdown file edited in vim?

Tags: vim-windows, macvim, filetype-markdown, unix

I use vim to edit `latex`, but latex is bit too heavy for taking notes casually on daily basis, so I decided to use markdown instead.

So, I want to configure vim so that I could view markdown formatted file using `\lv` command

I am using `Mac OS X 10.11`. How should I modify .vimrc file?

Comment: Have you searched for some plugins like [this one](https://github.com/suan/vim-instant-markdown)?

Comment: You don't need to preview markdown.

Comment: @romainl It would be nice if I can.

Comment: @statox that plugin solved the problem thank you very much.

Comment: @romainl Yeah and I don't need syntax highlighting. Doesn't discount the fact that it's useful.

Comment: @TommyA, who said anything about syntax highlighting?

Comment: @romainl I was drawing a parallel of "need vs. want".

Comment: As a general tool, I really like [when-changed](https://github.com/joh/when-changed) for a variety of tasks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

While I mostly agree with @romainl comment (markdown was made to be explicit enough not to need a preview) you can do this in different ways:

**[OSX / Unix]** The [instant-markdown plugin](https://github.com/suan/vim-instant-markdown) is a solution. You need to have node.js installed and to use the following command:

```
[sudo] npm -g install instant-markdown-d
```

You also need to have the packages `xdg-utils`, `curl` and `nodejs-legacy` installed.

With that when you open a markdown buffer, an html page will be opened in your web browser and you'll see the changes in real time.

---

**[Unix]** [This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/4141/90314) suggests to use the [daringfireball markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/downloads/Markdown_1.0.1.zip) program.

Once you have downloaded it you can use the following command to see the file in [lynx](http://lynx.browser.org/):

```
./Markdown.pl ~/testfile.markdown | lynx -stdin
```

You could use it in a Vim command with something like that:

```
:!./Markdown.pl % | lynx -stdin
```

---

**[Unix]** Another plugin which could be useful is [vim-preview](https://github.com/greyblake/vim-preview) it seems to have some dependencies but should work on markdown, rdoc, textile, ronn and rts files.

---

**[Windows / OSX]** Finally the github user natesilva made [a very good gist](https://gist.github.com/natesilva/960015) which only requires the `markdown` command in your path. Once you sourced the script <kbd>,</kbd><kbd>p</kbd> should open your markdown in the default browser.

```
"
" While editing a Markdown document in Vim, preview it in the
" default browser.
"
" Author: Nate Silva
"
" To install: Place markdown.vim in ~/.vim/ftplugin or
" %USERPROFILE%\vimfiles\ftplugin.
"
" To use: While editing a Markdown file, press ',p' (comma p)
"
" Tested on Windows and Mac OS X. Should work on Linux if you set
" BROWSER_COMMAND properly.
"
" Requires the `markdown` command to be on the system path. If you
" do not have the `markdown` command, install one of the following:
"
" http://www.pell.portland.or.us/~orc/Code/discount/
" http://www.freewisdom.org/projects/python-markdown/
"
function!PreviewMarkdown()
    " **************************************************************
    " Configurable settings

    let MARKDOWN_COMMAND = 'markdown'

    if has('win32')
        " note important extra pair of double-quotes
        let BROWSER_COMMAND = 'cmd.exe /c start ""'
    else
        let BROWSER_COMMAND = 'open'
    endif

    " End of configurable settings
    " **************************************************************

    silent update
    let output_name = tempname() . '.html'

    " Some Markdown implementations, especially the Python one,
    " work best with UTF-8. If our buffer is not in UTF-8, convert
    " it before running Markdown, then convert it back.
    let original_encoding = &fileencoding
    let original_bomb = &bomb
    if original_encoding != 'utf-8' || original_bomb == 1
        set nobomb
        set fileencoding=utf-8
        silent update
    endif

    " Write the HTML header. Do a CSS reset, followed by setting up
    " some basic styles from YUI, so the output looks nice.
    let file_header = ['<html>', '<head>',
        \ '<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">',
        \ '<title>Markdown Preview</title>',
        \ '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.3.0/build/cssreset/reset-min.css">',
        \ '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.3.0/build/cssbase/base-min.css">',
        \ '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.3.0/build/cssfonts/fonts-min.css">',
        \ '<style>body{padding:20px;}div#container{background-color:#F2F2F2;padding:0 20px;margin:0px;border:solid #D0D0D0 1px;}</style>',
        \ '</head>', '<body>', '<div id="container">']
    call writefile(file_header, output_name)

    let md_command = '!' . MARKDOWN_COMMAND . ' "' . expand('%:p') . '" >> "' .
        \ output_name . '"'
    silent exec md_command

    if has('win32')
        let footer_name = tempname()
        call writefile(['</div></body></html>'], footer_name)
        silent exec '!type "' . footer_name . '" >> "' . output_name . '"'
        exec delete(footer_name)
    else
        silent exec '!echo "</div></body></html>" >> "' .
            \ output_name . '"'
    endif

    " If we changed the encoding, change it back.
    if original_encoding != 'utf-8' || original_bomb == 1
        if original_bomb == 1
            set bomb
        endif
        silent exec 'set fileencoding=' . original_encoding
        silent update
    endif

    silent exec '!' . BROWSER_COMMAND . ' "' . output_name . '"'

    exec input('Press ENTER to continue...')
    echo
    exec delete(output_name)
endfunction

" Map this feature to the key sequence ',p' (comma lowercase-p)
map ,p :call PreviewMarkdown()<CR>
```

---

**Edit** @TommyA also suggested [grip](https://github.com/joeyespo/grip) this is not a vim plugin but it can be installed with `pip install grip`. The main advantage of this program is that it uses GitHub's markdown API so the render should be pretty close to what your markdown will look like on Github pages.

This program will serve your markdown files on `localhost:6419` by default. You should be able to invoke it from Vim with `:!grip`

Comment: There is also [grip](https://github.com/joeyespo/grip) which renders GitHub flavored markdown.

Comment: @TommyA instant-markdown also renders GitHub flavored markdown but another alternative is good too. Grip seems nice because it doesn't have to many dependencies (once you've used `pip` it seems like you're good to go). Thanks for your comment!

Comment: Ah missed that.  However, grip uses GitHub's markdown API.  So, it should always be rendered almost exactly how it'll appear on GitHub, including language highlighting and emoji.  There's also a [pull request](https://github.com/joeyespo/grip/pull/175) to get it to render WikiLinks.

Comment: @statox Is there a way to set vim such that `instant-markdown plugin` gets triggered for `.md` extensions?

Comment: @TommyA: Oh that's good to know. Do you want me to add it to my answer or do you want to make your own answer

Comment: @Tom I guess you can play with autocommands to do so ([`:h autocommand`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/autocmd.html#autocommand))

Comment: @statox All right. I'll have a look. Thank you.
`au BufNewFile,BufFilePre,BufRead *.md set filetype=markdown` this solved the problem.

Comment: @statox Go ahead and add it. I added the comment for people searching 

Comment: @TommyA: Ok then, thanks :-) @ Tom I'm glad you found a way

Comment: Yeah, `| lynx -stdin` is the way to do it (+1).  I'd just like to add that today pretty much **any** scripting language will have it's markdown processor.  On top of my head i know processors in `python`, `php` and `ruby`.  In all three of them writing a script that performs the same as (and often better than) `Markdown.pl` will take no more than 3 lines of code.